# Does anyone know whats wrong with my code im trying to make a fading slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a slideshow that fades in and out using jQuery but 
I cant seem to get it to go is something wrong in my code or do you guys have any other shortcuts to making this work?  Is there any other ways of making a fade in and fade out slideshow?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #wrap {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        height: 375px;
        width: 960px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #wrap img {
        display: none;
    }
    #wrap .is-showing {
        display: inline;
    }

    -->
    </style>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrap">
            <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="960" height="375" alt="image 1" class="is-showing" />
            <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="960" height="375" alt="image 2" class="is-showing" />
            <img src="images/image3.jpg" width="960" height="375" alt="image 3" class="is-showing" />
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1min.js" </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        slideshow();

        });

        function slideshow() {
            var showing = $('#Wrap .is-showing');
            var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next () ; showing.parent().children(':first');

        showing.fadeout(800, function() { next.fadeIn(800).addClass('.is-showing'); }).removeClass('.is-showing');

        setTimeout(slideshow, 2500);

        }


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: you have everything to create a jsfiddle.   Start there.

Comment: Are you sure your script tag linked jQuery correctly?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)
 in order to fix the issue?

Comment: i believe jquery is installed correctly i used a Jquery alert function to test and see if its working correctly...I also have the Jquery page saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `slideshow` function has a lot of errors, including typos, and it's not very thought-out. It's on the right track, though:

```
function slideshow() {
    var showing = $('#wrap > .is-showing');
    var next;
    if (showing.length === 3) {
        next = showing.parent().children(':first');
        showing.hide();
        showing.removeClass("is-showing");
        next.show();
        next.addClass("is-showing");
    } else {
        next = showing.next();
        next = next.length ? next : next = showing.parent().children(':first');
        showing.fadeOut(800, function() { next.fadeIn(800).addClass('is-showing'); }).removeClass('is-showing');
    }
    setTimeout(slideshow, 2500);
}
```